# How to map array into Avatar Element

Tags: html, reactjs

how to do the map that foreach item in the arry will be avatar element
example arry:

```
let arr = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4}]
```

the avatar element that i want that foreach item in the arry will be all this:
(i have tried something like that but it didnt work)
actualy my question is where and how to do the map function
Thanks in advance

```
 <div className="row">
                  {
                  arr.map((c,i)=><div key={c.id} className="col-sm d-flex  mb-3">c.id
                    </div>)
                  }
             
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <StyledBadge for
        overlap="circle"
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "right"
        }}
        variant="dot"
      >
        
        <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg" />
      </StyledBadge>
 
    </div>
     </div>
```

=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using the map function correctly, but you have to put the object inside a jsx element in between object paranthesis

```
  {
      arr.map((c,i)=> <div key={c.id} className="col-sm d-flex  mb-3">
                         {c.id}
                      </div>
  }
```